# jQuery animation not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am coding my website, and a friend of mine was helping me. This code does not work on IE 10 (Windows 7). I even tried the legacy modes and to no avail. Upon clicking on "services" for example, this code would work on FF or Chrome. But, not on IE. Can someone help me fix this code so it would also work on IE?

```
$('#services-fr-2').on('click',function(){

    $(".clientsFr").hide();
    $('.servicesFr').fadeToggle();
    $('#green-pouch-fr').animate({
        'top':'450px'//,
        //'height':'450'
    });

});
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the fiddle as requested.

http://jsfiddle.net/dVMT9/5/

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Semicolon at the end of the `on()` function? Sometimes IE can be picky about stuff like this.

Comment: No, none at all. @Jacedc, will try that

Comment: Break it down line-by-line until you figure it out.  Get rid of everything in the click callback.  If it works, add those in one at a time until you break it.  I highly doubt the problem is in the code you're showing here.

Comment: @MidevilChaos can you create a jsfiddle? That way all of us can try debugging the code.

Comment: Please describe what the actual error is - "this code does not work on IE 10" isn't descriptive enough to actually provide a good answer. What about it doesn't work? Do you get an error? This is probably a good time to introduce you to http://www.jslint.com/ as well.

Comment: Goyuix there is no error. JSlint picks up nothing except the regular $ error in relation to jslint (as it always does).

All that should happen, does not happen. I tried every line one by one. But the JS code refuses to execute on IE. My rectangle should go down and adjust to the amount of text (in the fiddle the text won't appear, which is fine I suppose, since there are not separate html files to be used).

Comment: For those interested, check the fiddle in the edited post :)

Comment: Open developer tools on IE using F12 and see if the page is being rendered in quirks mode or some older compatibility

Comment: I can't see any problem with [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TJWY/) in IE10 (it works in a same way as in FF), just assign a jQuery library to your code...

Comment: @ yuvi, tried that. But it changed nothing in terms of JS.

Comment: @Teemu. If it works on FF and Chrome on my side, does that not indicate that I am using a library? Of course I am, although I took your advice and re-used it by changing library versions. Alas, to no avail. I even tried the jquery one itself.

Comment: @MidevilChaos There's no jQuery library attached in the fiddle you've linked...

Comment: -_- you could attach one in the fiddle? Oh. In any case, I always use the Google one (been taught that Google has a vast one). I use the latest.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing brackets.

```
$('#services-fr-2').on('click',function(){  
        $( ".clientsFr" ).hide();
        $('.servicesFr').fadeToggle();
        $('#green-pouch-fr').animate({
            'top':'450px'//,
            //'height':'450'
        })
});
```

Comment: IE is usually picky about errors. Chrome/FF probably fixes them on the fly. I guess.

Comment: No, I simply forgot to paste the brackets. They are already there.

Comment: That isn't true at all.  Chrome/FF fixes nothing, and are just as picky, syntax wise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the comma after `'top':'450px'`

The comma would be fine if the next line wouldn't be commented out. Remove the comma and IE will be fine.

Comment: I commented the comma. I still removed it just now though just in case (IE might have been dumb here? But no, it  wasn't).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be `px` in `'top':'450px'`, I once had a issue with `px`, just try removing them

Comment: I wish it was that! How I wish it would be that simple. But sadly it isn't. Thank you for the advice though, will be useful in the future for certain.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in IE9.  I tried top without quotes and it worked.

Comment: This is should be in comment section. This is not good answer.