# jQuery animate function attached to AngularJS scope variable not working in IE or Edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

There are all sorts of similar questions on this site. Most of them turn out to be syntax errors. Examples:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473742/jquery-animation-not-working-in-internet-explorer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797924/jquery-animation-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314620/jquery-animate-not-working-in-ie), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333911/jquery-animate-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-ie), etc.

I've confirmed I have to correct syntax for `.animate()`:

[jQuery Documentation for .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

I've cheked the documentation for `.fadeIn()`:

[jQuery Documentation for .fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

As far as I can tell, everything has been done right. It works in Chrome, FF, Safari, etc. Just not on Edge or IE.

This code is created in a route-based Angular Controller:

```
this.animateOverlay = function() {
        $("#main-content-overlay").fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 1000}).animate({top: "+=65px"}, 1000);
    };
    this.animateOverlay();
```

This is the CSS associated with `#main-content-overlay`:

```
#main-content-overlay {

    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;

}
```

And this is the HTML element:

```
<img src="images/home/main-content-overlay.png" id="main-content-overlay" />
```

I'm hoping that I do have a syntax error somewhere, and that Microsoft hasn't made a technological face-plant with Edge, but so far I've been unable to figure out exactly what's wrong with this simple animation in IE and Edge.

This should be an equivalent [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5c41hxLv/).

Comment: Can you wire up a jsFiddle?

Comment: @MathewBerg, I've added an equivalent JSFiddle.